# Vagrantにrailsをインストールするもエラーがでる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, vagrant

Vagrantにrailsをインストールしてもmemoプログラムを作成するもエラーがでて、初期表示できません。
rails 5.1.6　centOS6.8

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Memos#index
Showing /home/vagrant/rails_lessons/note/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
Rails.root: /home/vagrant/rails_lessons/note
```

application.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Note</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
```

下の二行をコメントアウトしたらエラーは消えました。

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

gccのバージョンアップ試みるもだめでした。

- `sudo yum -y install gcc-c++`　→インストール済で何もしませんとでる
- `sudo yum install nodejs npm`　→上記同じ

コメントアウトしなくてもエラー解消できるようご指導お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

以下のようなエラーがいくつか出ていますが、これらはツールの動作に必要なライブラリのバージョンと、OSにインストールされているライブラリバージョンが合わない場合に表示されるものです。

```
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
```

ツール側では `glibc-2.14` 以上を要求していますが、CentOS6 の環境だと `glibc-2.12` までしかリリースされていません。
glibc などはOSのコアで利用されているパッケージになるので、ディストリビューションで提供されているバージョンより上げるのは難しいでしょう。

取りうる選択肢としては、

- OSのメジャーバージョンを上げる (CentOS7なら `glibc-2.17` なので恐らくOK)
- rails や node のバージョンをCentOS6で動くものに下げる
  (具体的にどのバージョンなのかまでは私は分かりかねます)