# Cloud9 web3.py インストール後実行時にglibcのエラーが出るようになった

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-linux, ethereum, aws-cloud9

AWS Cloud9(Amazon Linux)を使用し、Etherreum smartcontractへ接続するLambda+API Gatewayの開発をしています
言語はpython3.6
パッケージのインストールは以下の通りです

```
$ pip install web3==5.11.1 setuptools==49.6.0 -t .
$ ../venv/bin/pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver web3==5.11.1 setuptools==49.6.0
```

エラーになるコードです

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from web3 import Web3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    return ''
```

8月末(最後に取得した日付ははっきりせず...)までは、上記の内容で開発が出来ていたのですが、本日新たに作成したものは、以下のエラーが出るようになりました
CloudWatchから取得したエラーは以下の通りです

```
Unable to import module 'hogehoge/lambda_function': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /var/task/rusty_rlp.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

web3の使用を止めるとエラーは出ないので、web3のパケージで問題が起きているようです

現在 glibcのバージョンは以下の通りです

```
$ yum list installed | grep glibc
glibc.x86_64                         2.17-292.180.amzn1            @amzn-updates
glibc-common.x86_64                  2.17-292.180.amzn1            @amzn-updates
glibc-devel.x86_64                   2.17-292.180.amzn1            @amzn-updates
glibc-headers.x86_64                 2.17-292.180.amzn1            @amzn-updates
```

パッケージのバージョンは固定にしていたのに、なぜエラーになるかわかりません
バージョン指定を解除しても同じエラーになります
glibcを上げれば済むのかわかりませんが、対処方法を教えていただけないでしょうか

他に提示すべき情報もあればご指摘ください

---

指摘いただき試したことは以下の通りです

- コードをEC2サーバ上で実行
  lambdaから離れ、EC2(ubuntu18.04)で動作するコードか確認しました
  想定どおりの動作です
- パッケージをlayer化し、lambdaで実行
  使用するパッケージ(web3.py)をlayer化しlambdaで実行しました
  同じglibcのエラーが出ました
- Cloud9(ubuntu18.04)を作成し、実行
  同じglibcのエラーが出ました
- Cloud9(AmazonLinux2)を作成し、実行
  環境を作ることが出来ず確認出来ませんでした
  cloud9からec2(AmazonLinux2)にsshするところまでは出来たのですが、それ以降やることがわからずLambdaFunctionの作成すまでいたりませんでした
- 他のAWSアカウントで作成した類似環境での実行
  同じAmazonLinux1で開発していた環境を利用
  同じglibcのエラーが出ました

AmazonLinux2が力不足で確認できていませんが、他にありませんでしょうか

---

対応内容記載しましたが、記載場所が適切ではない指摘をいただきましたので改めます

Comment: 追記された内容については、個別の回答として投稿すべきかと思います。(質問はあくまで "質問" の体裁を保つ必要があります)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のエラーは、ツール等が要求したライブラリバージョンに対して OS にインストールされた glibc のバージョンが合わない (=主にOS側が古い) 場合に表示されます。

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found
```

※ほぼ同じ内容ですが、同じく glibc のエラーに関して私が [過去に回答したもの](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/65338)

yum で参照しているパッケージバージョン (2.17-292.180.**amzn1**) から察するに、今現在は Amazon Linux **1** を使っているんじゃないかと思われます。

しかし Amazon Linux 1 では glibc 2.17 までのサポートのようなので、glibc 2.18 以降が必要な場合には、Amazon Linux **2** の環境を用意する必要がありそうです。

**参考:** (別ツールに関する回答ですが、glibc のエラーに対する説明は参考になると思います)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/595730

> This is because you are using Amazon Linux 1 -- i.e. Amazon Linux (2013.03+) which supports up to GLIBC_2.17.

Comment: Amazon Linux2ではなく、Ubuntu 18.04で試しました。glibcは2.27です。ですが同じエラーが出ました。上がっていれば良いというものではないのでしょうか。他にも試してみます。

Comment: あれから色々試しましたが改善しません。EC2(Ubuntu18.04)で実行できたコードを、Lambdaに移しパッケージ部分をLayerにしましたが、同じエラーが出ます。もうどうして良いのかわからない...

Comment: コメント欄では一部のユーザーにしか通知が飛ばないので、「追加で試したこと」「新たに分かったこと」があれば質問本文を編集した方がみんなの目に留まりやすくなります。

Answer (score 0):

AWSサポートに問い合わせし回答受領及び対応出来ました

根本原因は`rusty_rlp`のバージョンでした
8/28に0.1.14 -> 0.1.15に上がり、そこでglibc 2.18を必要とすることになったようです

AWSからの回答も、cubickさんからあったように、AmazonLinux2を使うようにということでした
ただその場合、python3.8を使用する必要があるのですが、私の力不足でEC2(AmazonLinux2)+Cloud9(ssh)の環境が構築出来ず方法を変えました

web3をpipする際に、`web==3.5.11.1 rusty_rlp==0.1.14`とし、AmazonLinux1のまま開発を続けることとしました
これにより最初に記載したテストコードが通るようになりました

ありがとうございました